# ndbclient native library is missing in Mysql Cluster installation

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-cluster

I get following error when trying to run ClusterJ based Java application:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ndbclient in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.tie.ClusterConnectionServiceImpl.loadSystemLibrary(ClusterConnectionServiceImpl.java:68)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.tie.ClusterConnectionServiceImpl.create(ClusterConnectionServiceImpl.java:87)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.core.SessionFactoryImpl.createClusterConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:263)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.core.SessionFactoryImpl.createClusterConnectionPool(SessionFactoryImpl.java:245)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.core.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:193)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.core.SessionFactoryImpl.getSessionFactory(SessionFactoryImpl.java:139)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.core.SessionFactoryServiceImpl.getSessionFactory(SessionFactoryServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.core.SessionFactoryServiceImpl.getSessionFactory(SessionFactoryServiceImpl.java:27)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.ClusterJHelper.getSessionFactory(ClusterJHelper.java:72)
    at com.mysql.clusterj.ClusterJHelper.getSessionFactory(ClusterJHelper.java:57)
```

In my MySql Cluster 7.4 installation under Windows I have ndbclient_static.lib file in lib catalog. Java is unable to read lib files the way it is expressed in MySql manuals. As I understand I should have ndbclient.dll there but it is missing. How to proceed to get ClusterJ working?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 packages in 7.4 release: ZIP and MSI. I have found library in ZIP package.